# Inscribed circle in a trapezoid

Tags: geometry

BA = 3. The radius of the circle is 2. What is DC?

I know that AG = AF = 1. And i know that FC = CE. And DC = DE + EC. I drew a line from point A to line DC to create a right triangle, but I can’t figure out where to go from there

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think that this answers your question. DC=6 (because FC=EC)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Attach a coordinate system to the figure, and let its origin be at point $D$.

Then $Z = (2, 2)$, and $A = (3, 4) $, and $C = (x_1, 0) $

When want to solve for $x_1$ such that the distance between $Z$ and $AC$ is $2$.

The equation of $AC $ is $ y - 4 = \dfrac{-4}{x_1-3} (x - 3) $

We want to make sure the coefficients of $x$ and $y$ are negative.

Applying the distance formula using the above line equation and the point $Z = (2,2)$, we obtain

$ d = 2 = \dfrac{ -2 + 4 - \dfrac{4}{x_1 - 3} (2 - 3) }{ \
\sqrt{1 + \dfrac{16}{(x_1 - 3)^2}}} $

From which,

$ 4 \left( 1 + \dfrac{16}{(x_1 - 3) ^2 } \right ) = \left(2 + \dfrac{4}{x_1 - 3}\right)^2 = 4 + \dfrac{16}{(x_1 - 3)^2} + \dfrac{16}{(x_1 - 3)}  $

So that,

$\dfrac{ 3 }{ ( x_1 - 3) ^ 2 } = \dfrac{1}{ (x_1 - 3) } $

And therefore,

$ (x_1 - 3) = 3 $

Hence $x_1 = 6 $

And this is equal to the the length $DC$.

Comment: The correct answer is 6 as the triangles $ZFA$ and $CFZ$ are similar, the latest being congruent with $CEZ.$

Comment: Yes.  Thank you.  I've corrected the solution.